# show logo on action bar in api 21

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I try to show icon in action bar with below codes:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

but instead of show `R.drawable.ic_launcher` logo, it shows back button like below image:

[image]

I used:

- api 11 for min sdk,
- api 21 for target sdk,
- api 21 for compile sdk,
- buildtool 22.0.1,
- Android studio 1.2.2,

what should i do? tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setLogo()` or `setIcon()` method, none of them will work if you haven't set the `DisplayOptions` properly.

Just do this,

```
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | 
   ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
   actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

You can customize the constants as you like.

**UPDATE**

Please add this to hide the back button,

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Or can I help in any other way?

Comment: I added your code, the logo apeared! but the back button is showing yet!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Instead of

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "up" affordance indicator is provided by a drawable specified in the homeAsUpIndicator attribute of the theme. To override it with your own custom version it would be something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>
</style>
```

If you are supporting pre-3.0 with your application be sure you put this version of the custom theme in values-v11 or similar.